# Scan statements executed before print

Tags: c, eclipse, printf, scanf

I have this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
     int dogs;
     printf("How many dogs do you have?\n");
     scanf("%d", &dogs);
     printf("So you have %d dog(s)!\n", dogs);
     return 0;
}
```

To my knowledge, when executing, the program will say 'How many dogs do you have' and I enter a number. Instead, I get a blank page, and I have to first enter a digit. Then I get

How many dogs do you have?
So you have 3 dog(s)! (if I input 3)

I am using Eclipse + MinGW, and its my first time using C, so I'm not sure what I have/had to set up.

Comment: I'd say your having issues with Eclipse. [See it live](http://ideone.com/VSeGaD).

Comment: I would say so too. It works fine on CodeBlocks. Not sure what I have though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it still failing with Eclipse and MinGW if you try to flush `stdout` in between the first `printf` and the `scanf`?

Comment: @DennisMeng If it does, I have zero faith in MinGW; stdout is supposed to flush-on-newline.

Comment: It is indeed an Eclipse problem. I researched and apparently, there is a plugin you can download to fix it. You can find it here (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732)

Comment: @The__Malteser If you post an answer with that link and a summary of the Eclipse bug, I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. The problem was that eclipse was first processing all the scan statements, and then processing all the print statements. This would be hard to solve if your program has more than one scan statement.

The fix is somewhat simple. Download the binary fix from the [following link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732).

You then need to paste the starter.exe in the path where you have Eclipse installed.

In my case it was this eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_64_5.2.0.201309180223\os\win32\x86_64

Yours may very a bit. Overwrite the existing starter.exe and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` buffers output. In general (in UNIX) stdlib is smart enough to flush `stdout` before reading `stdin` but it might not be the case in MingW. Consider using `fflush()` or outputting to stderr.

Comment: `\n` is required to flush the output buffer, this is not conforming behavior. The link posted above suggests that `fflush(stdout)` does actually work, here, but this definitely appears to be one of those rare occasions where the compiler actually is wrong.